# cannot find hello_qiskit module

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm currently following the "Introduction To Quantum Programming" course of qiskit.

At the beginning of "Visualizing entanglement" chapter :
https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/visualizing-entanglement

We have to run this line:
`from hello_qiskit import run_puzzle`

This raises this error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello_qiskit'

I cannot find the hello_qiskit module in my anaconda environnement
And if I try to install it with

`pip install hello_qiskit`
I have this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> hello_qiskit (from versions: none) ERROR: No
> matching distribution found for hello_qiskit

How can I install this module or is there another way to use the run_puzzle function ?

Comment: Hello, could you put the link to the course you're talking about please?

Comment: Hello, i just add it, thank you

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to set up the environment? https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-prerequisites/environment-setup-guide-to-work-with-qiskit-textbook

Comment: Yes I did, and everything I followed in the course until this stage worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hello_qiskit` is just a python file that lives in the Qiskit Textbook Jupyter Notebook system that is used as a short-cut/helper to interact with `qiskit_textbook.games.hello_quantum`. In [Visualizing Entanglement](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/visualizing-entanglement), if you add

```
import hello_qiskit
help(hello_qiskit)
```

to the first cell, you will find a file `/home/jovyan/hello_qiskit.py` that contains the `run_puzzle` method, defined as follows:

```
from qiskit_textbook.games import hello_quantum

def run_puzzle(j):
    puzzle = hello_quantum.run_game(exercises[j]['initialize'],
                           exercises[j]['success_condition'],
                           exercises[j]['allowed_gates'],
                           exercises[j]['vi'],
                           qubit_names=exercises[j]['qubit_names'],
                           mode=exercises[j]['mode']
                          )
    return puzzle
```

This method references a list `exercises` of dictionaries defining arguments that will be passed to the `run_game` method. When you pass an `int` to the `run_puzzle` method, you are simply indexing the `exercises` list defined in `hello_qiskit.py`. For example, `run_puzzle(0)` accesses `exercises[0]`, which is defined as

```
{
    'initialize': [],
    'success_condition': {},
    'allowed_gates': {'0': {'x': 3}, '1': {}, 'both': {}},
    'vi': [[1], True, False],
    'mode': 'line',
    'qubit_names': {'0':'q[0]', '1':'q[1]'}
}
```

To see how the `run_game` method is used, see [Hello Qiskit Game](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-ex/hello-qiskit.html).